# BCC sent to BTC paper wallet

Tags: paper-wallet, cross-chain-recovery

I sent Bitcoin cash to a Bitcoin paper wallet. I think it is wrong because the transaction on public key give me 0 BTC.
What can I do to recover my Bitcoin cash?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking the transaction on a BTC or BCH explorer ?

You have to sweep the private key (of the paper wallet) in a bitcoin cash wallet.

I used Coinomi on Android (be sure to select Bitcoincash) with success.

Comment: Thanks! With bitinfocharts.com i see my transaction! Now I try with Coinomi to withdraw. Thanks a lot!!!